# What does "taken up" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, articles

> Naked mRNA is not readily taken up by cells, but needs to be encased inside a protective envelope to gain entry.

In this sentence, I'm confused by the phrase *taken up*. After searching a dictionary, I'm even more bemused. I just couldn't find a meaning that matches this sentence appropriately. But I do have a hypothesis that according to one of the items of the meaning of "take up" in the dictionary, which is to begin a friendly or romantic relationship with (someone), I guess that maybe *taken up* is used as a figurative way to suggest that cells and mRNA can't coordinate well enough to function normally. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

By the way, I noticed that *but* is used in this sentence for conveying logical meaning. But it's more logical for me to use *so*. Can anyone explain why *but* is used as such?

Comment: It means that the cells don't absorb, or take in, the RNA easily. I couldn't find a dictionary definition for this sense, but I'm certain that's what it means.

Comment: OED defn 13d *To use up (esp. a commodity or **resource**); to **consume***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a dictionary definition for the phrasal verb "to take up" in the Oxford English Dictionary which seems relevant here. It has many definitions, and you have to scroll way down a huge page to find it. I have also included a recent citation.

> **To take up**
>
> **20**
>
> **a**. transitive. Of a substance or body: to absorb (a fluid, moisture, etc.); to interact with and retain (a gas or other
> substance); to dissolve (a solid).
>
> 2011   I. Fraser & P. Marsack Bush Capital Year 133   *The fungus too
> takes up food via its network of mycelial threads.*

Source: [oed.com](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/197158?rskey=P6RDHD&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid50655001)

Comment: Well done. I don't have access to the OED.

Comment: @KateBunting - yeah it requires a login unfortunately. If you are in the UK, sometimes public libraries allow you to access it for free.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence above could be rephrased as two separate sentences:

> Naked mRNA is not readily **taken up** by cells.
>
> Naked mRNA needs to be encased inside a protective envelope to **gain entry**.

Here, to “gain entry” appears to be synonymous to being “taken up,” as the sentence’s structure suggests.